# How do I get a measure of effect size for each term in a multilevel model?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, effect-size

For a multilevel model of the form, say:

$$Y_{ij} = B_0 + B_1X_{1_{ij}} + B_2(X_1)^2_{ij} + B_3X_{3_{ij}} + B_4X_{1_{ij}}X_{3_{ij}} + B_5X_{5_j} + (u_0 + u_{1_j} + e_{0_{ij}} + e_{1_{ij}})$$

Does anyone have any pointers on how I might get a measure of the effect size for each term (i.e. comparing coefficients of terms measured in different units)?  I was thinking of using Z-values, but then surely I'd be testing for significance rather than effect size?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I put your formula in $\LaTeX$.

Comment: You're welcome. Please make sure I did it the way you wanted. In particular $B_5$ has only a j subscript - that's how you had it, but perhaps it was a typo.

Comment: Yep, it's is a Level 2 effect! Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter estimates are measures of effect size; you can also divide them by their standard errors, for a standardized effect size. Unfortunately, in such a complex model (interactions and quadratic terms) the interpretation is going to be complicated. This is not because this is a multilevel model - the same is true for "regular" regression.

I find that the best way to get a clear sense of such complex models is to calculate the predicted values for various typical combinations of $X_1$ through $X_5$ and then maybe graph them as well.